# How do I perform debug and release configuration builds

Tags: c#, .net-core

In previous .NET Core I could do the following:-

```
{
  "configurations": {
    "Debug": {
      "compilationOptions": {
        "define": [
          "DEBUG",
          "TRACE"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Release": {
      "compilationOptions": {
        "define": [
          "RELEASE",
          "TRACE"
        ],
        "optimize": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it seems to be replaced by buildOptions but is a single configuration. What is the intended method now and how do I create this in the latest .NET Core?

Comment: What do you mean by "In previous .NET Core "? What version of .Net Core do you use?

Comment: I'm using Preview 2 of the SDK and 1.0 installer, the latest available at https://www.microsoft.com/net/download. Based on the documentation at https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file it indicates the configuration options was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace `compilationOptions` with `buildOptions`

```
"configurations": {
  "Debug": {
    "buildOptions": {
      "define": [ "DEBUG", "TRACE" ]
    }
  },
  "Release": {
    "buildOptions": {
      "define": [ "RELEASE", "TRACE" ],
      "optimize": true
    }
}}
```

Comment: It's as simple as that!